# Две стадии выборов сразу?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Похоже, сейчас стадии предварительного голосования и выборов доступны одновременно.
Зачем нужна стадия предварительного голосования и почему она до сих пор доступна?

Comment: А вы можете изменить голос на второй вкладке?

Comment: @Discord, нет :) "Голосование за этого кандидата заблокировано". Но стрелочки видно.

Comment: Ну вот и ответ: там отображаются результаты.

Comment: @Discord, у вопросов с historical lock тоже отображаются результаты, но стрелок нет :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кроме предварительного голосования доступна еще и стадия выдвижения кандидатов. Думаю, это сделано для того, чтобы избиратели, которые впервые пришли на страницу выборов на последнем этапе, могли:

- Прочитать комментарии под заявками и задать новые вопросы кандидатам (первая вкладка)
- Оценить общую степень поддержки кандидатов (вторая вкладка)

Возможно, открытые результаты предварительного голосования — это не очень хорошо, т.к. они побуждают голосовать «как все». С другой стороны, спрятать результаты было бы странно — мы бы обменивались ими в чате или хранили где-то.

Ненажимаемые кнопки полезны для того, чтобы помнить, как вы голосовали на предварительном этапе. Там до сих пор показываются оранжевые стрелочки.